# Powershell command to save a Hyper-V Guest state to disk

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Does anybody know the command to save the state of a hyper-v guest-os from powershell?

Ex)

Save-VM GuestName ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://pshyperv.codeplex.com
The PowerShell module there for Hyper-V management has the cmdlets for working with virtual machines.

In the above module, for discovering and manipulating Machine states:

```
Get-VMState
Set-VMState
Convert-VmState
Ping-VM
Test-VMHeartBeat
Shutdown-VM
Start-VM
Stop-VM
Suspend-VM
```

So, to answer your question, to save VM state, the cmdlet will be `Set-VMState`

If you don't want to use any module and write your own function using WMI, take a look at MSDN documentation for Hyper-V WMI interfaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723874(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ravikanth's answer looks complicated and takes a lot of reading.. but this works for me:

```
Stop-VM -name vmName
```

Or type: `Get-VM | Stop-VM -save` to put all machines in a saved state.